# How to run a Intellij IDEA created Maven project with Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jenkins

I have created a Maven (java) project in IntelliJ IDEA on MacOS. It has the standard directory structure, like this:

```
myproject
   |
   -- src -- main -- java -- My java code goes here
   |   |
   |   ----- test -- java -- junit test code goes here
   |
   -- pom.xml
   -- myproject.xml
```

My project is to generate a jar file. In IDEA, I have been able to run Maven build to generate jar file as well as run junit test.

Now, I want to use Jenkins to do CI test for my project. I have setup a Jenkins on a Linux box. Jenkins can pull the entire project structures to the Linux box.

My question is, on Linux, given the directory structure that is created by IntelliJ IDEA, how can I run maven to packet jar file and run junit test?

Comment: `mvn package`... Then I forget the command to run the tests, but maybe `mvn test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory is not specific to IDEA, it is infact the standard maven structure.  If you go to project configurations of your Jenkins maven project you will see a section where you can declare your pom.xml and the goals you want to run.

Comment: To elaborate, first you need to configure Jenkins to know about your Maven installation (in the global Jenkins settings). Then, create a "Maven job". Let it download your sources (via git?), and in the main part of the job execute some maven goals. I recommend "mvn clean verify", which includes running all tests.